# Failed to resolve: firebase-database-15.0.0 Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:G:/MyApplication/app/build.gradle">app</a>

Tags: android

```
Failed to resolve: firebase-database-15.0.0
Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:G:/MyApplication/app/build.gradle">app</a>
```

**showing this:**

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   Inspection info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).  Issue id: GradleCompatible

please help me to fix it

Comment: Please post your build.gradle (project) file.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply sir, now it has solved,